# How to display the scale of the vector layers (e.g. polylines) in leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, scale, polyline

I want to add the scale of the line/polyline that I have drawn at a certain length on the map in the leaflet. How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean the distance? You can go over each `latlng` of the polyline and call `distanceTo`

Comment: For example, there is a 100 meters long line drawn using the "L.polyline" command on the map. Actually this line is 1 meter long. How to express this by adding a specific scale bar on the map?

Comment: Is there any solution to convert 100 m to 1 m in the scale bar?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want ... Do you want to display the current scale of the map or do you want that a polyline has other dimesions? Maybe you are looking for: [Scale Control](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#control-scale)

Comment: I have a 1 meter long polyline on the map. Since I could not see this polyline on the map on a small scale, I enlarged it by multiplying it by 1000 meters. However, the scale I added to the map with Scale.Control does not represent the actual length of this polyline. How to adjust the scale to know the actual length of this polyline?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the value of the control when you update the function [_updateMetric](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/436430db4203a350601e002c8de6a41fae15a4bf/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L87) and [_updateImperial](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/436430db4203a350601e002c8de6a41fae15a4bf/src/control/Control.Scale.js#L94) functions.

Your code can look like:

```
scale = L.control.scale().addTo(map);
scale._updateMetric = function (maxMeters) {
        var meters = this._getRoundNum(maxMeters),
            label = meters < 1000 ? meters + ' m CUSTOM' : (meters / 1000) + ' km CUSTOM';

        scale._updateScale(this._mScale, label, meters / maxMeters);
    };
scale._update()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/v5trLy4a/